# Saving a checkbox value in Yii

Tags: yii

I can't figure out how to properly save checkbox values in Yii. I have a MySQL column, `active`, defined as a `tinyint`. I have the following form creation code, which correctly shows the checkbox as checked if the value is 1 and unchecked if 0:

```
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'active'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'active'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'active'); ?>
```

And the code to save the form correctly changes other, text-based values:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    if(isset($_POST['Thing']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Thing'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('thing/index'));
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

The value of `active` is not saved. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is the error you see? 
After `$model->attributes=$_POST['Thing'];`, what is the value for $model->active?
What are the validators currently associated with active field (see rules() function)? 
Have you tried using Gii to auto-generate CRUD operation, so you can compare codes?

Comment: Thanks Antony, I didn't realize a rule was required for every input. I added `array('active', 'boolean')`, which solved the problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For every input that you are accepting from user, you need to define it in model::rule(). is active defined there in rule()?

Comment: actually if you just define it in your rules as an integerOnly, the yii is smart enough to know it has to convert a bool to an int and the checkbox code bit is smart enough to understand what a 0 and 1 stands for (actually in PHP, any integer can be use as a bool)

Answer (score 20):

You can use htmlOptions array to specify value attribute. Below is the code example:

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'active'); ?>
<?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'active', array('value'=>1, 'uncheckValue'=>0)); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'active'); ?>
```

> Since version 1.0.2, a special option named 'uncheckValue' is
>   available that can be used to specify the value returned when the
>   checkbox is not checked. By default, this value is '0'.
>   *(This text is taken from YII Documenration)*

Comment: This works with non numeric values as well, for example <?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'active',array('value' => 'Y', 'uncheckValue'=>'N')); ?>

Answer (score 6):

In general, if you are having problems saving to the database, i would replace

```
$model->save();
```

with

```
if($model->save() == false) var_dump($model->errors);
```

that way, you can see exactly why it did not save. it is usually a validation error.

Answer (score 6):

Please follow:
 1. in protected/models/Thing.php add active as a numeric

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('active', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            //OR optional 
            array('active', 'safe'),
    );
}
```

Controller action: Its ok

View:

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'active'); ?>
<?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'active', array('value'=>1, 'uncheckValue'=>0)); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'active'); ?>
```

Hope this will work for you...

Answer (score 2):

Article which can be helpful when figuring out how to handle booleans & checkboxes in Yii

http://www.larryullman.com/2010/07/25/handling-checkboxes-in-yii-with-non-boolean-values/

Answer (score 1):

I used a bit type field in my DB and it didn't work.

```
1.- I changed the field type to tinyint
2.- In the rules function added:
    array('active','numerical'),
3.-In the form (as D3K said) do: 
    <?echo $form->checkBox($model,'active',array('value'=>1, 'uncheckValue'=>0));?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check by printing all the attributes which are being captured. If active is not captured, it must not be safe. you need to declare the variable as safe or define a rule around that variable. This will make the variable safe.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar the same problemce before,I change data type is int,so it save

Answer (score 0):

We can also add a rule as `safe` in `model` to pass the values from `form` to `controller` without missing.

```
array('active', 'safe'),
```

Answer (score 0):

well this post is so old but I've found a solution very useful specially for giving checkbox a value specified rather than number. The new syntax is something like this 
notice I'm using ActiveForm

field($model3, 'External_Catering')->checkbox(['id' => 'remember-me-ver', 'custom' => true,'value'=>"External_Catering", 'uncheckValue'=>"vide"]) ?>

1) where my model is =>model3

2) with the name External_Catering

3) that take the value External_Catering and empty when it's uncheckValue

4) in Controller you get the value just by specifying the model and it's attribute like
  $External_Catering=$model3->External_Catering.